# make a toogle_visibility(Javascript) in asp way

Tags: javascript, asp.net, blackberry

**I use BB 5(not support Javascript yet)**
I created a web mobile that have a `toogle_visibility()` function(Javascript). Now the problem is, it seems that Blackberry browser can't "read" Javascript code. Is there any way to make a `toogle_visibility()`(Javascript) in asp way?(including the top-down animation if possible, in other words **as similiar as possible**)
I use `ASP/C#` languange to my web mobile. Thanks :D

**Edit**(Just to make my question clearer) : **How to create a `toogle_visibility()` without using Javascript?** :D

**This is my Javascript code which is working in regular browser(non-BB browser)**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if($("#"+id).is(":hidden"))
          $("#"+id).slideDown();
        else
             $("#"+id).slideUp();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What code exactly are you generating?... BlackBerry can run all kinds of JavaScript in fact they have a whole development framework to build apps using HTML5/JavaScript called WebWorks.

Comment: @scunliffe Thanks :D Ok, i will show my JS code, i think BB can run JS but not all of it...

Comment: If you just call $('#'+id).toggle(); does it work? And if not which BlackBerry OS version are you targeting?

Comment: I think its not working..i use OS5. Thanks :D